# How do I split a string with tidyr::separate in R and retain the values of the separator string?

Tags: r, tidyr, stringr

I have a data set:

```
crimes<-data.frame(x=c("Smith", "Jones"), charges=c("murder, first degree-G, manslaughter-NG", "assault-NG, larceny, second degree-G"))
```

I'm using tidyr:separate to split the charges column on a match with "G,"

```
crimes<-separate(crimes, charges, into=c("v1","v2"), sep="G,")
```

This splits my columns, but removes the separator "G,". I want to retain the "G," in the resulting column split.

My desired output is:

```
 x         v1                       v2
 Smith     murder, first degree-G   manslaughter-NG
 Jones     assault-NG               larceny, second degree-G
```

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: `sep = "(?<=G),"`?

Comment: Looking at the data, it seems like `sep = ', '` would be the practical choice.

Comment: Yes, that would work, but my actual data has commas mixed in the string. So 'G, ' is the only practical separator. But I cannot figure out how to keep the 'G' when using it as part of the separator string.

Comment: I've adjusted the data example in original question to make it more clear why I need to separate using 'G, '

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE**

This is what you ask for. Keep in mind that your data is not tidy (both V1 and V2 have more than one variable inside each column)

```
A<-separate(crimes,charges,into=c("V1","V2"),sep = "(?<=G,)")
A
      x                      V1                        V2
1 Smith murder, first degree-G,           manslaughter-NG
2 Jones             assault-NG,  larceny, second degree-G
```

---

An easier way to get keep the "G" or "NG" is to use `sep=", "` as said by alistaire.

```
A<-separate(crimes, charges, into=c("v1","v2"), sep = ', ')
```

This gives

```
      x         v1              v2
1 Smith   murder-G manslaughter-NG
2 Jones assault-NG       larceny-G
```

If you wanted to keep separating your data.frame (using the -)

```
separate(A, v1, into = c("v3","v4"), sep = "-")
```

that gives

```
      x      v3 v4              v2
1 Smith  murder  G manslaughter-NG
2 Jones assault NG       larceny-G
```

You'll need to do that again for the v2 column. I don't know if you want to keep separating, please post your expected output to make my answer more specific.

Comment: Sorry, my example didn't include the real world case of my data, which has commas mixed in with the charges. So the "G, " is necessary as the extractor string to differentiate from ", " which exist.

Comment: And my desired out put is: 
   x          v1               v2
1 Smith   murder-G   manslaughter-NG

Comment: Huge props @Matias Andina. That worked great. Now on to further cleaning. As you noted, my data is not tidy. Not yet anyway.

Answer (score 12):

Replace `<yourRegexPattern>` with your Regex

**If you want the 'sep' in the left column (look behind)**

```
dataframe %>% separate(column_to_sep, into = c("newCol1", "newCol2"), sep="(?<=<yourRegexPattern>)")
```

**If you want the 'sep' in the right column (look ahead)**

```
dataframe %>% separate(column_to_sep, into = c("newCol1", "newCol2"), sep="(?=<yourRegexPattern>)")
```

Also note that when you are trying to separate a word from a group of digits (I.E. `Auguest1990` to `August` and `1990`) you will need to ensure the whole pattern gets read.

Example:

```
dataframe %>% separate(column_to_sep, into = c("newCol1", "newCol2"), sep="(?=[[:digit:]])", extra="merge")
```

Comment: Unfortunately the look behind does not work for non-fixed length patterns.