# Regex match the last occurrence of a character in a string

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, data-manipulation

I would like to match the last occurrence of "," in a string to be able to `separate` a column properly.

Sample data

```
tibble(
  name = c("John", "James"), 
  company_num = c("Apple, Inc, 1000",
                  "Microsoft, 1200")
)
```

The desired output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  name  company      num
  <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
1 John  Apple, Inc  1000
2 James Microsoft   1200
```

What I have tried

```
df %>% 
  separate(col = company_num, 
           into = c("company", "num"), 
           sep = ", ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's a one-line tidyverse solution here but here's a base R method:

```r
# Get location of last comma
widths  <- regexpr(",[^,]*$", df$company_num)

# Treat company_num as fixed width format file
df[c("Company", "Number")]  <- read.fwf(
    textConnection(df$company_num), 
    widths,
    col.names = c("Company", "Number")
)

# Remove trailing comma/space
df$Company  <- sub(",\\s?$", "", df$Company)

df

# A tibble: 2 x 4
#   name  company_num      Company    Number
#   <chr> <chr>            <chr>       <int>
# 1 John  Apple, Inc, 1000 Apple, Inc   1000
# 2 James Microsoft, 1200  Microsoft    1200
```

#### Update - tidyverse solution

If it must be tidyverse, then borrowing **heavily** from the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36586673/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-tidyrseparate-in-r-and-retain-the-values-of-the-s) question, you could do:

```r
df |>
    separate(
        col = company_num, 
        into = c("company", "num"), 
        sep = "(?=[[:digit:]])", extra="merge"
    ) |>
    mutate(
        company = sub(",\\s?$", "", company),
        num = as.numeric(num)
    )

# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#   name  company      num
#   <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
# 1 John  Apple, Inc  1000
# 2 James Microsoft   1200
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately, for the teams peace of mind - I really need a tidyverse/tidyr solution with `separate`

Answer (score 2):

With the `stringr` package and regex, in particular [positive lookahead or lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), with `(?=lookahead)` and `(?<=lookbehind)`.

Assuming your dataframe or tibble is `df`:

```
df %>% mutate(

company = stringr::str_extract(company_num, ".*(?=,.*$)"),
#  ↑ capture the text BEFORE a comma that is followed by one or several character ".*" at the end of the string "$"

num = stringr::str_extract(company_num, "(?<=, )[0-9]*$")) %>%
# ↑ capture one or several digits at the end of the string ($), preceded by ',' 

select(-company_num)
# ↑ drop the "company_num" col
```

Answer (score 2):

With the correct regex, you can use `separate` in a single line.

This put the comma in a capture group `(, )`, where this comma cannot have another comma behind it `(?!.*,)`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% separate(company_num, into = c("company", "num"), sep = "(, )(?!.*,)")

# A tibble: 2 × 3
  name  company    num  
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>
1 John  Apple, Inc 1000 
2 James Microsoft  1200
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub` like.

```
data.frame(x[1],
           company = sub(",[^,]*$", "", x$company_num),
           num = sub(".*, ", "", x$company_num))
#   name    company  num
#1  John Apple, Inc 1000
#2 James  Microsoft 1200
```

Data

```
x <- data.frame(name = c("John", "James"), 
                company_num = c("Apple, Inc, 1000", "Microsoft, 1200") )
```